# Jquery .width() results are different in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, width

I am trying to measure the width of a string. To do this I create a div width the string as value, add it do the DOM and measure the width using Jquery's .width().

The problem is that I get different results in when I execute the script in Firefox and Chrome.

I created a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7wjeB/2/

HTML:

```
<body>
<div>
    <input id="input" value="office worker" style="display:block; position:static; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 25px;"></input>
    <button onclick="calc()" style="font:Arial; font-size:12px;">Calculate width</button>
</div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
width = function(font, string) {

    var f = font || '12px arial', o = $('<div>' + string + '</div>').css({
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'float' : 'left',
        'white-space' : 'nowrap',
        'visibility' : 'hidden',
        'font' : f
    }).appendTo($('body')), w = o.width();
    o.remove();
    return w;
};

calc = function() {
    var content = $("#input").val();
    var font = $("#input").css("font-size") + " " + $("#input").css("font-family");
    alert(width(font, content));
};
```

I am using Firefox version 19.0.2 and Chrome version 26.0.1410.64

Comment: I get 144 in both browsers.

Comment: My question is, why is this important to you? A web developer should ASSUME that text will be rendered somewhat differently in different browsers, not be surprised by it.

Comment: @j08691 I get 139 in Chrome and 144 in Firefox (on Windows 7) using the latest (stable) versions of both browsers.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - and you're letting me know this why?

Comment: @j08691 To show others that this isn't a problem local to Armin.

Comment: @Blazemonger Ok I formulated my question wrong. It's not really a problem, I just was just curious why the width differs from browser to browser and looking at the other comments isn't even consistent in the same browser.